# go install always attempts to use GOROOT and GOPATH is not listed under go env

Tags: go

I'm having a quite frustrating problem with the `GOPATH`, which, despite being set in `.profile`, is not appearing when invoking `go env`, and does not appear to be affecting the `go install` target location.

I'm attempting to use `go install` to install packages, and am getting this error, which clearly shows that it is attempting to install in `/usr/lib/go`, rather than the intended directory of `/home/me/dev/go`.

```
$ go install github.com/songgao/colorgo
go install github.com/songgao/go.pipeline: mkdir /usr/lib/go/pkg/linux_386/github.com: permission denied
```

`go env` gives the following results.

```
$ go env
GOROOT="/usr/lib/go"
GOBIN=""
GOARCH="386"
GOCHAR="8"
GOOS="linux"
GOEXE=""
GOHOSTARCH="386"
GOHOSTOS="linux"
GOTOOLDIR="/usr/lib/go/pkg/tool/linux_386"
GOGCCFLAGS="-g -O2 -fPIC -m32 -pthread"
CGO_ENABLED="1"
```

But it most certainly *is* set.

```
$ echo $GOPATH
/home/me/dev/go
```

**Update:** I have exported GOPATH in `~/.profile` and sourced it, but I'm still having the same problem.

```
$ export GOPATH=/home/me/dev/go
$ go env
GOROOT="/usr/lib/go"
GOBIN=""
GOARCH="386"
GOCHAR="8"
GOOS="linux"
GOEXE=""
GOHOSTARCH="386"
GOHOSTOS="linux"
GOTOOLDIR="/usr/lib/go/pkg/tool/linux_386"
GOGCCFLAGS="-g -O2 -fPIC -m32 -pthread"
CGO_ENABLED="1"
```

**Update again:** This problem has ceased since I upgraded to go1.1beta2. I'm not sure what was wrong, because `GOPATH` appeared to be set correctly, but it's all apparently working now.

Comment: Have you exported `GOPATH`?  Shell variables are only passed on to executed commands if you export them.

Comment: Is `go` aliased to some other command or wrapper script?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`GOPATH` and workspaces](http://golang.org/doc/code.html)

```
$ mkdir -p $HOME/dev/go/src
$ mkdir -p $HOME/dev/go/bin
```

In `$HOME/.profile`:

```
export GOPATH=$HOME/dev/go:
export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/dev/go/bin
```

Then reboot or log out and log in.

As soon as you have logged in, before anything else, run:

```
$ env | grep -i '^GO'
GOPATH=/home/me/dev/go
$ cat $HOME/.profile
```

What output do you get?

Comment: Reboot is a bit harsh :) Log out and log in should suffice, and `source ~/.profile` in a shell will update that shell, useful for quick testing.

Comment: Reboot is totally not necessary.

Comment: I've made sure to export `GOPATH` and followed those instructions without any luck.

Comment: See my revised answer. What output do you get?

Comment: This specifically didn't quite solve my issue, (though upgrading to go1.1beta2 did), but it is the most informative.

Comment: Instead reboot or relogin, you can simply `source ~/.profile` to reload your configuration. :D

Comment: the ´export´ part of setting the line where you set your ´GOROOT´ is very important...

Answer (score 0):

As you gave evidence for having set GOPATH, the second part of your question - GOPATH is not listed under go env - may be caused by the "go env" of your installed version. Neither go1 (linux) nor go1.0.2 (windows) versions of "go env" display GOPATH. If you look at the source (GOROOT/src/cmd/go/env.go), you'll find right at the top the list of elements to display (mkEnv) which starts with GOROOT and does **not** contain GOPATH.

Version go1.0.3 (windows) does display GOPATH; the corresponding list in the source, however, starts with GOARCH.

I admit that this does not solve the first part of your problem - (trying to) install into GOROOT - but perhaps the above will help you to focus on the culprit (build process).

Answer (score 0):

I think it's quite clear that go install everything in your GOTOOLDIR, GOTOOLDIR is also related with GOROOT:

> Yours: GOROOT="/usr/lib/go"

According to [Document](http://golang.org/doc/install):

> Install the Go tools
>
> The Go binary distributions assume they will be installed in /usr/local/go (or c:\Go under Windows), but it is possible to install them in a different location. If you do this, you will need to set the GOROOT environment variable to that directory when using the Go tools.
>
> For example, if you installed Go to your home directory you should add the following commands to $HOME/.profile:
>
> export GOROOT=$HOME/go
>
> export PATH=$PATH:$GOROOT/bin
>
> Windows users should read the section about setting environment variables under Windows.

You should follow these steps to change your GOROOT, instead of GOPATH, then everything should work.

If it's not work, change GOTOOLDIR as well.

Answer (score 0):

Create a soft link, then copy the *go* binary in `/usr/local` as follow:

```
# ln -sf /usr/local/go/bin/go /usr/bin/go
```