# go install always uses GOROOT/bin instead of GOPATH

Tags: linux, go, debian

I'm having annoying issue with `go install` command.

Every time I try to run it within the `src` directory of my **GOPATH** the resulted file is getting created in **GOROOT/bin** directory for some reason.

I verified my environmental variables in .bashrc and also run 'go env' (see below) and couldn't find any issues:

**.bashrc**

```
export GOBIN=$HOME/dev/src/go/bin
export GOPATH=$HOME/dev/go-dev
export PATH=$PATH:$GOBIN:$GOPATH/bin
```

**go env**

```
GOARCH="amd64"
GOBIN="/home/user/dev/src/go/bin"
GOCHAR="6"
GOEXE=""
GOHOSTARCH="amd64"
GOHOSTOS="linux"
GOOS="linux"
GOPATH="/home/user/dev/go-dev"
GORACE=""
GOROOT="/home/user/dev/src/go"
GOTOOLDIR="/home/user/dev/src/go/pkg/tool/linux_amd64"
CC="gcc"
GOGCCFLAGS="-g -O2 -fPIC -m64 -pthread"
CGO_ENABLED="1"
```

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15846914/go-install-always-attempts-to-use-goroot-and-gopath-is-not-listed-under-go-env) has a similar problem except I have GOPATH in my env (I tried the solution but it didn't help).

When I tried to create the test library [using official GoLang site](http://golang.org/doc/code.html) and run **go install** I've got a proper file created in $GOPATH/pgk/linux_amd64 but not in the bin directory.

Am I missing something in my configuration?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[Official documentation](http://golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-GOPATH_environment_variable) about the `go` tool:

> If DIR is a directory listed in the GOPATH...
>
> If the GOBIN environment variable is set, commands are installed to the directory it names instead of DIR/bin

There has been a discussion about this topic on the [mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/golang-nuts/-mN8R_Fx-7M) where this is further explained:

> (a) If you don't set your GOBIN env variable, 
>   you get the Go compiler binaries going in GOROOT/bin
>   whereas the your binaries are going in GOPATH/bin.
>   (I personally like this separation of binaries.)
>
> (b) If you set your GOBIN to anything, then 
>   both the Go binaries and your binaries are going to GOBIN.

The solution in your case would be to not set your `GOBIN`.

Comment: In my case it wasn't working because 'permission denied' despite GOBIN being $HOME/go/bin

Comment: In my case (Windows 8), `go install` would only create binaries in `%GOROOT%\bin` and not `%GOPATH%\bin`. I only have `GOROOT` and `GOPATH` set. I had to set `GOBIN` to `%GOPATH%\bin` to get `go install` to create binaries in `%GOPATH%\bin`.