# Intellij Golang cannot find a module

Tags: go

I am using Golang plugin for IntelliJ, after set the GO Sdk for the module and project. I tried to edit configuration for the project. When I click the edit configuration, in module dropdown box, it shows no module. it seems the configuration cannot find the module. Anything that I missed? I have issue the following command in order to make Go SDK work in Intellij.

```
      # mkdir /usr/lib/go/bin
      # ln -s /usr/bin/go    /usr/lib/go/bin/go
      # ln -s /usr/bin/godoc /usr/lib/go/bin/godoc
      # ln -s /usr/bin/gofmt /usr/lib/go/bin/gofmt
```

Answer (score 3):

In the recent version of IntelliJ (here is screenshot from Ultimate 2019.1.3) you can find the GOROOT and GOPATH in `Preferences` -> `Language & Frameworks` -> `Go` -> `GOROOT`/`GOPATH`.

1. Install to Golang in your system (I used brew):

   > Since OSX ElCapitan, the OSX forbid access to `/bin` directory, which would cause problems with compiling the project with the default settings and having error like:
   >
   > Cannot run program "/bin/go" (in directory "/Users/XXX/go/src/YYY/ZZZ/service"): error=2, No such file or directory
   >
   > So this should be solved by updating GO preferences.
2. Open IntelliJ and your go project and update GOROOT in your project

   [image]
3. If you have a custom directory of GOPATH do update it as well.

   [image]
4. Click to run your go program.

Answer (score 3):

this works for me:

1. Close GoLand.
2. Navigate to the project root, backup and delete .idea
   directory.
3. Open the IDE again.

by https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/GO-11854

Answer (score 1):

Try the [recent latest releases of that plugin](https://github.com/go-lang-plugin-org/go-lang-idea-plugin/releases), to see if the issue persists.

Note that you shouldn't have to link anything, just set your [`$GOROOT` environment variable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15895908/6309) (or not, as mentioned [in this article](http://dave.cheney.net/2013/06/14/you-dont-need-to-set-goroot-really)), and [your `$GOPATH`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15846956/6309).

Comment: I can confirm that the latest releases (1.0.0 ones) shouldn't require any path fiddling from the users.